# copy a string with special chars from a file, into another file after a keyword

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have a file that contains a random string value with special chars, i need to copy that content and paste it in another file right after the keyword "echo".

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop zpa-connector
sudo touch /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo chmod 644 /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo echo | tee /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
cat /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo systemctl start zpa-connector
```

Example expected result:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop zpa-connector
sudo touch /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo chmod 644 /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo echo 'azd516/*651az654daz[#lc,nzpmoa156' | tee /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
cat /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo systemctl start zpa-connector
```

How can i achieve that? Thanks for your help

Side question: i dont know if the content pasted after the echo should be in double or simple quotes

Comment: Why are you asking the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77146576/escape-special-chars-when-using-sed)?

Comment: [edit] your question to show what you've tried so we can help you with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```bash
$ cat file
azd516/*651az654daz[#lc,nzpmoa156

$ cat script
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop zpa-connector
sudo touch /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo chmod 644 /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo echo | tee /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
cat /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo systemctl start zpa-connector

$ v=$(< file)
$ sed -E "s|^(sudo echo)( \|.+)$|\1 '$v'\2|" script
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop zpa-connector
sudo touch /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo chmod 644 /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo echo 'azd516/*651az654daz[#lc,nzpmoa156' | tee /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
cat /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo systemctl start zpa-connector
```

this `sed` command captures the existing string of interest into two groups, and places the content of the variable `v` (which contains the string from the other file) between them. It uses `|` as a separator as the default one (`/`) is present in your string.

If however you know that your variable might change and might include unknown characters, you're better off using `awk`:

```bash
$ v=$(< file)
$ export v
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=" |"}{if ($0 == "sudo echo | tee /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key") {print $1 "\047" ENVIRON["v"] "\047" ,$2} else {print $0}}' script
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop zpa-connector
sudo touch /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo chmod 644 /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo echo 'azd516/*651az654daz[#lc,nzpmoa156' | tee /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
cat /opt/zscaler/var/provision_key
sudo systemctl start zpa-connector
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the string content is fundementally random, it could contain any ASCI character. As for AWK, i have no objection on using it if you have such a solution  - i would be binaraly grateful, thanks again

Comment: @YassineBoumajane I've added an `awk` solution too

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW if you put `v="$v"` on the same line as and immediately before `awk` then you won't need to `export v`, i.e. `v="$v" awk ...` all on one line.